# How to display the image on screen which is taken from camera

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-image-picker

I am using `react-native-image-picker` to take image.

Below is the code for this:

```
const chooseImage = () => {
    ImagePicker.launchCamera(
      {
        mediaType: 'photo',
        includeBase64: false,
        maxHeight: 1000,
        maxWidth: 1000,
        quality: 0.5,
        cameraType: 'front',
      },
      (response) => {
        console.log(response);
        if (response.didCancel) {
          console.log('User cancelled image picker');
        } else if (response.error) {
          console.log('ImagePicker Error: ', response.error);
        } else if (response.customButton) {
          console.log('User tapped custom button: ', response.customButton);
        } else {
          console.log(response);
        }
      },
    );
  };

<TouchableOpacity onPress={chooseImage}>
    <Text style={styles.title}>Selfie Screen</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

In console I am getting output as:

```
{height: 1000, uri: "content://com.tericsofttask.imagepickerprovider/ca…lib_temp_12aafb95-496e-4796-a6d8-8f29eaa3b78f.jpg", width: 750, fileName: "rn_image_picker_lib_temp_12aafb95-496e-4796-a6d8-8f29eaa3b78f.jpg", type: "image/jpeg", …}
fileName: "rn_image_picker_lib_temp_12aafb95-496e-4796-a6d8-8f29eaa3b78f.jpg"
fileSize: 11569
height: 1000
type: "image/jpeg"
uri: "content://com.tericsofttask.imagepickerprovider/cacheDir/rn_image_picker_lib_temp_12aafb95-496e-4796-a6d8-8f29eaa3b78f.jpg"
width: 750
__proto__: Object
```

Now I want to display the image taken on screen. But I am not able to figure it out. I don't want to open gallery and then choose image. I want to display the image on screen instantly. Please help

**EDIT**
I made few changes :

```
const chooseImage = () => {
    ImagePicker.launchCamera(
        {
            // ....Same as previous
        },
        (response) => {
            // ... Same as previous
            } else {
                let source = response.uri;
                setImageSource(source);
                console.log("imgSrc: ", imageSource);
            }
        },
    );
};
```

Console output:

```
imgSrc:  content://com.tericsofttask.imagepickerprovider/cacheDir/rn_image_picker_lib_temp_c61dd0cc-2a46-4987-af5d-2b21ac87548b.jpg
```

Then I tried to show that on my screen:

```
<View style={styles.container}>
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={chooseImage}>
        <Text style={styles.title}>Selfie Screen</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
    <Image
        source={{ uri: imageSource }}
        style={styles.imageBox}
        resizeMode='contain'
    />
</View>
```

But nothing appears on the screen.

Answer (score 1):

Upon analyzing the response object, I do notice a field named 'URI' (Uniform Resource Identifier). Which basically, represents the PATH to the `image`.

[image]

Use this path and pass it as source to `Image` to display the image.

```
 <Image source={{ uri: PATH_SHOULD_BE_HERE }} />
```

### References

- [Image Component](https://reactnative.dev/docs/image)
- [React Image Picker Guide](https://blog.crowdbotics.com/how-to-use-react-native-image-picker/)

Comment: I have an edit in my post. Can you please see it.

Answer (score 0):

That might be a basic mistake, but you should check the `styles.imageBox` style, once the width and height are mandatory for data images and you didn't include it on the example.

> Note that for network and data images, you will need to manually specify the dimensions of your image!